# Is it possible to implement dynamic text on a screen in a Flutter app based on the route to that screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that contains a to-do list.

When users create an entry for the to-do list, there is example text in the textboxes that they complete for the entry.

There are three different ways for users to open the to-do list. Each of these ways is characterized by different information. For the sake of example, let's call them Apple, Banana, and Orange.

When users open the to-do list, I would like the example text to reflect which way they used to open the to-do list. For example, if they opened it from the Apple screen I would like the example text to be about apples. If they opened it from the banana screen, I would like it to be about bananas.

Is this possible in Dart/Flutter? If so, how would you implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried sending parameters to the screen you're opening?

```
Navigator.push(
  context, 
  MaterialPageRoute((context)=> NewScreen(type: Type.bananas))
);
```

where your `NewScreen` class would be similar to:

```
class NewScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  final Type type;
  
  const NewScreen({required this.type});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    switch(type):
      case (Type.bananas):
        return Image.asset('bananas.jpg');
      ...
  }
}
```

And your `Type` would be like:

```
enum Type{bananas, apple, oranges}
```